# Webpack 2: static-site-generator-plugin "self is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I've some problem with [static-site-generator-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin).

In my project I'm using:

- **webpack** v2.1.0-beta.27
- **static-site-generator-webpack-plugin** v3.1.0
- **react** and **react-dom** v15.4.1

It's a single page website.

Here is a part of `webpack.config.babel.js` file:

```js
import StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin from 'static-site-generator-webpack-plugin'
  
export default {
    entry: {
        main: './components/Root/index.jsx',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), './public'),
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
  
      plugins: [
        // ...
        new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin('main', '/', {}),
      ]
        // ...
  }
```

And this is `./components/Root/index.jsx` file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import HTMLDocument from 'react-html-document'

import App from '../App/index.jsx'

export default function (locals, callback) {
    const MyHtml = (
        <HTMLDocument
            title='My Page'
            metatags={[
              { name: 'description', content: 'My description' },
            ]}
            scripts={[ `${locals.assets.main}` ]}>
            <App />
        </HTMLDocument>
    )

    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(MyHtml, locals.assets)
    callback(null, '<!doctype html>' + html)
}
```

When I'm trying to use it I see the Error message: `ERROR in ReferenceError: self is not defined`. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error with **webpack-dev-server**. The cause of this error is rendering on a server. The server doesn't have the object **self**. You can use `scope` option (https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin#scope) or just avoid to use static-site-generator-webpack-plugin on the server.

If you use **webpack-dev-server** to solve this error you have to set `inline: false` (https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server#inline-mode).
If you want to use Hot reload in your root URL, without an iframe, just add `<script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` to your page (https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server#inline-mode-in-html).

Comment: A friggin `inline: false` property solved it. Cannot believe it. You Den deserve a cookie.